# .NET MVC contact form with dynamic/fillable "from" address

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, smtp, emailrelay

I'm having issues coding my contact form in order to properly send e-mails with a "From" address that the user fills in. I get 5.7.1 responses informing me that the address doesn't belong to my account.

I know wordpress makes this possible however I'm not sure what the fault is on my C# project. I'm not sure if the sending host is supposed to be an e-mail account created on my domain for this purpose or should the credentials be from the machine I'm hosting on?

The project is depoyed to azure websites.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(cvm.FromMail, "myaddress@domain.com", cvm.Subject, sb.ToString());
          SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
          smtp.Host = "mydomain.host.com";
          smtp.Port = 587;
          smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
           smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
          smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myaddress@domain.com", "*********");
          smtp.EnableSsl = true;
          smtp.Send(Mail);
```

I've tried many different combinations of port/ssl settings but still can't find success doing this.

Or should the host/credentials be something from my source azure website machine instead of my domain credentials?

Comment: Are you attempting to use your Azure VM as a SMTP relay or is this a separate service?

Comment: The credentials I'm currently trying to use are from a separate service (where I have my domain name and also a different server). I'm wondering if the reason for the 5.7.1 error is because I'm using my other service and that maybe for some reason, azure .net allows only it's own relay

Comment: I suspect it's a transport / network security issue rather than a code issue. You should being troubleshooting there. Ensure that your relay has whitelisted your azure server IP.

Comment: I'm fairly limited by the server I was trying to send the e-mails with so I'll try to do it through the azure smtp and see if it helps